# pd.read_clipboard() giving me an error on Python 2

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

### THIS MY CODE

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pandas import Series,DataFrame

import webbrowser
website = 'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NFL_win-loss_records'
webbrowser.open(website)

nfl_frame = pd.read_clipboard()
```

#### BELOW IS THE ERROR MESSAGE

```
CParserError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-2e5b27c84e34> in <module>()
----> 1 nfl_frame = pd.read_clipboard()

C:\Users\Sam\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\clipboard.pyc in read_clipboard(**kwargs)
     49         kwargs['sep'] = '\s+'
     50 
---> 51     return read_table(StringIO(text), **kwargs)
     52 
     53 

C:\Users\Sam\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.pyc in parser_f(filepath_or_buffer, sep, delimiter, header, names, index_col, usecols, squeeze, prefix, mangle_dupe_cols, dtype, engine, converters, true_values, false_values, skipinitialspace, skiprows, skipfooter, nrows, na_values, keep_default_na, na_filter, verbose, skip_blank_lines, parse_dates, infer_datetime_format, keep_date_col, date_parser, dayfirst, iterator, chunksize, compression, thousands, decimal, lineterminator, quotechar, quoting, escapechar, comment, encoding, dialect, tupleize_cols, error_bad_lines, warn_bad_lines, skip_footer, doublequote, delim_whitespace, as_recarray, compact_ints, use_unsigned, low_memory, buffer_lines, memory_map, float_precision)
    560                     skip_blank_lines=skip_blank_lines)
    561 
--> 562         return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    563 
    564     parser_f.__name__ = name

C:\Users\Sam\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.pyc in _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    323         return parser
    324 
--> 325     return parser.read()
    326 
    327 _parser_defaults = {

C:\Users\Sam\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.pyc in read(self, nrows)
    813                 raise ValueError('skip_footer not supported for iteration')
    814 
--> 815         ret = self._engine.read(nrows)
    816 
    817         if self.options.get('as_recarray'):

C:\Users\Sam\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.pyc in read(self, nrows)
   1312     def read(self, nrows=None):
   1313         try:
-> 1314             data = self._reader.read(nrows)
   1315         except StopIteration:
   1316             if self._first_chunk:

pandas\parser.pyx in pandas.parser.TextReader.read (pandas\parser.c:8748)()

pandas\parser.pyx in pandas.parser.TextReader._read_low_memory (pandas\parser.c:9003)()

pandas\parser.pyx in pandas.parser.TextReader._read_rows (pandas\parser.c:9731)()

pandas\parser.pyx in pandas.parser.TextReader._tokenize_rows (pandas\parser.c:9602)()

pandas\parser.pyx in pandas.parser.raise_parser_error (pandas\parser.c:23325)()

CParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 7, saw 3
```

Comment: What were the contents of your clipboard at the time you ran the program? You do realize, don't you, that the lines in your program are executed sequentially, in very rapid fashion? As soon as the call to `webbrowser.open()` is complete, `pd.read_clipboard()` will be executed. Your program as-is doesn't give you any time to switch to your browser, scroll through the loaded page, and copy whatever information you want to put into the DF.

Comment: I'm working with jupyter notebook so I do not run all the code at the same time. I'm trying to copy nfl best win–loss record in division data(the data is in a table form with rows and columns as usual). After I copy the data to clipboard and I run this line "nfl_frame = pd.read_clipboard()" I get an error. In the tutorial the tutor has his running just fine no error. I cant seem not get a solution to this problem.

Comment: Try to copy data from website before executing 
nfl_frame = pd.read_clipboard()